# How to create PHP inline hover effect?

Tags: php, css, hover, effect

I'm having problems creating some hover effect.

I have `

```
<p class="proCalBand" style="border-left: 10px solid '.$row["act_format"].';"><a href="'.$page_url.'"><img src="'.$row["custom4"].'" class="slikca" /></a>
```

I want

```
style="border-left: 10px solid '.$row["act_format"].';"
```

to be **15px** when hover over it how can I acomplish this? (maybe some slower transition would be great also ;) )

Is this even possible?

I tried **onmouseover**` but it's not working.

Any Ideas?

Thank you
R

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use pure css to change just the `border-width` from 10px to 15px on `:hover` like this:

```
p.proCalBand {border-width:10px;}
p.proCalBand:hover {border-width:15px;}
```

Comment: Already tried that but it's not working at all. I think it has to be inline somehow.

Comment: You could remove the inline style altogether and set the borders via css or js, and it will work. Also, If you change the inline style to remove the `border` property, and declare `border-style` and `border-color` inline only, and then use `border-width` as above in the stylesheet, it will work.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working because the color of the border is called via the setting inside my CMS and can be diferent everytime  '.$row["act_format"].' so if I delete this inline style nothing will show up, or it will be the same color no matter what I choose inside my CMS settings. Hope you understand. Thank you

Comment: Right,  `.$row["act_format"]` is the color from the css, correct?, so you html element could look like this: `<p class="proCalBand" style="border-color: .$row['act_format'].">` and then in your css use `p.proCalBand {border-style:solid;border-width:10px;} p.proCalBand:hover {border-width:15px;}`.

Comment: Yeeees, exactly!! Working like a charm. What a simple solution and couldn't think of it... Thank you million times. Here is what I was trying to achieve. ;) http://www.bi-center.eu/si/napovednik